# 404 error handling through .htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

im actually new to .htaccess concept, and i've read some articles about it. The thing is i wanna control a 404 document not found error.i have placed the .htaccess file on the root directory and also i have created a error_pages folder in which i have my 404.html file. And i have also checked my AllowOveride line and its set to All. I have the following line in the .htaccess file but its not working and its saying:

> The requested URL /Add Friend/abc.php was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Now i've checked many similar questions but they went up through my head.

.htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/404.html
```

Comment: did you check if the .htaccess is being used? put some random junk in there to see if you get a 500 internal error.

Comment: have you tried accessing the 404 url document directly in your browser ? are the permissions on the file/dir set correctly ?

Comment: @MarcB..yeah i have tried it already and yeah its giving me internal server error.. and its specified in the 404 error also..after the additionally part.

Comment: @Calimero..yeah im accessing localhost/Add friend/abc.php
this abc.php doesnt exists.

Comment: I'd prefer not using blanks in document pathes. Should be escaped to %20 as well.

Comment: And Calimeros comment was whether you are able to access the error document via the browser. Does yourhostname.tld/error_pages/404.html work?

Comment: the error_pages/404.html works fine.. but its the .htaccess file couldn't redirect to 404.html when a 404 error occurs..

Comment: The .htaccess is syntactically correct, and is interpreted by the server correctly, as the servers error message shows. So it almost certainly is a path or filename issue. Maybe .html instead of .php?

Comment: @syck. i have created 404.php file, and also updated it in .htaccess. but same error

Comment: That was merely a suggestion. You could try using the full path from your browser for the `ErrorDocument 404`. But I think it will end up being found as a typo somewhere. Any redirects applying somewhere? Check your access log to find out which files are actually accessed.

Comment: i've already tried the full path like localhost/Add friend/error_pages/404.html
but then its gives internal server error..

Comment: To make it working set `AllowOverride All` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html)

Comment: localhost/Add friend/error_pages/404.html??? Where is it hosted? In a subdirectory of /Add friend or in the document root? `/error_pages/404.html` locates the error_pages in the document root.

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Please read the question and the comments. AllowOverride has been ruled out before as a cause.

Comment: @syck sorry, there are a lot of unformatted text, I have missed it. Now see

Comment: @syck.. i have made a project named Add Friend in htdocs. and in add friend i have created the error_pages folder. isn't its the root directory of my project???
the folder wan't supposed to be located here, was it??

Comment: Most probably the htdocs folder is the document root of your **server**.

Comment: ohhh..im such an idiot. Thanks for bearing me man. i've placed the folder in htdocs and now its working..Thankss.. :)

Comment: Great =) You can always check for your document root with `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` and it is also contained in `phpinfo();` output. And please, do never use blanks in your pathes, because that only leads to complications.